# How to iterate through `newtype` List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, newtype

For that `newtype` is treated as a whole different type in the type system, I'm wondering if there is any way to use pattern matching or iterate a list with newtype, as follow.

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo [Int]

bar :: Foo -> Int
bar (x : xs) = x + bar xs
bar [] = 0
```

Comment: Try `bar (Foo (x : xs)) = x + bar (Foo xs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options.

1. Just manually wrap/unwrap the newtype right in place.

   ```
   bar (Foo (x : xs)) = x + bar (Foo xs)
   bar (Foo []) = 0
   ```
2. Implement the function on lists, and unwrap it once before passing to the function. In this case the list version is just `sum`, so we can use

   ```
   bar (Foo xs) = sum xs
   ```
3. Make an interface that allows to manipulate `Foo` values as if they were lists.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

   {-# COMPLETE (:%), FooNil #-}

   pattern (:%) :: Int -> Foo -> Foo
   pattern x :% xs <- Foo (x : (Foo -> xs))
    where x :% xs = Foo (x : getFoo xs)

   pattern FooNil :: Foo
   pattern FooNil = Foo []

   bar :: Foo -> Int
   bar (x :% xs) = x + bar xs
   bar FooNil = 0
   ```
4. Abstract. You don't really need the particular list deconstructors, you just need some way to implement a *fold* over the contained data. There is a standard [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable) class in `base` for just this, but it would require you container to be parametric over the contained type. Since it's not parametric, you need to use [`MonoFoldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable) class from the `mono-traversable` package instead.

   ```
   import Data.MonoTraversable

   type instance Element Foo = Int
   import MonoFoldable Foo where
     ofoldr f (Foo (x:xs)) e = f x $ ofoldr f (Foo xs) e
     ofoldr _ (Foo []) e = e

   bar = ofoldr (+) 0
   ```

Note that generally, this sort of function should be implemented with a *strict left fold* instead of a right fold.